# Facebook hashtag feed

Tags: facebook, rss, hashtag, facebook-feed

Is there any? I've searched and I didn't find anything about it. I need feed or posts IDs of specific #hashtag, iframe with this would also works.

Anyone, anything?

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is only the keyword search, hashtags are not supported (yet): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

Answer (score 0):

There will be the Keyword Insights API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights/ ), but it's currently not publicly available. So, the only option is as @luschn described.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's finally deprecated.

> Public Post search is no longer available.
>   (/search?type=post&q=foobar)

[LINK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found solution, someone has created http://www.facebook-hashtag.com service, even it is limited to 2 minutes of searching.